# Error en @Override al usar CLASE

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, fileupload

Estoy tratando de usar una clase, la cual me marca unos errores, me marca el siguiente mensaje "Method does not override method from its superclass" pero no entiendo el porque, espero me puedan ayudar.

Clase:

```
public class MyReceiver extends UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onProgress(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo) {
    // your implementation
}

@Override
public void onError(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo, ServerResponse serverResponse, Exception exception) {
    // your implementation
}

@Override
public void onCompleted(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo, ServerResponse serverResponse) {
    // your implementation
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo) {
    // your implementation
 }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
      <action 
android:name="com.yourcompany.yourapp.uploadservice.broadcast.status" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Lo que tiene en la clase `UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: Eso es una librería: compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'  @acklay

Comment: Daniel, ¿quizá no hayas configurado el inicializador [como muestra el creador de la clase](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/wiki/Setup)? Él además [dice lo siguiente](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/wiki/Monitoring-upload-status#global-broadcast-receiver-): *Cambie `com.yourcompany.yourapp` por lo que tenga configurado en `UploadService.NAMESPACE` en el setup inicial...* Ahí tienes que poner **el paquete y nombre real de tu aplicación**, la cual cual quizá no esté en un paquete llamado `com.yourcompany` ni se llame `yourapp`. Lo mismo ocurre con el manifest.

Comment: No había visto eso @A.Cedano, lo del paquete y nombre de la aplicación en el manifest si lo hice, entonces en el configurado de la aplicación debe de ir en el main o en la misma clase?

Comment: Según dice el desarrollador (1er enlace de mi comentario anterior), debes poner esto en el método `onCreate` de tu clase inicial (`MainActivity`  supongo, o la que sea): `@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        UploadService.NAMESPACE = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
        // Or, you can define it manually.
        UploadService.NAMESPACE = "com.yourcompany.yourapp";
    }` observa que hay dos formas de hacerlo, debes elegir una. `APPLICATION_ID` supongo debe ser una constante que debe estar definida en cualquier parte de tu App.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano voy a ver si lo puedo hacer funcionar, espero que así sea